# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-list' not found. 'user-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Tutorial 5: Relationship and Hyperlink API Errors
Tutorial link address is：https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/
I tried query-related solutions, and encountered similar problems on stackoverflow, but after testing, I still couldn't use them.

views.py

```
class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)


class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'snippets': reverse('snippet-list', request=request, format=format),
    })


class SnippetHighlight(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    path('', views.api_root),
    path('snippets/', views.SnippetList.as_view(), name='snippet-list'),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.SnippetDetail.as_view(), name='snippet-detail'),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/highlight/',  views.SnippetHighlight.as_view(), name='snippet-highlight'),
    path('users/', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
])
urlpatterns += [
    path(r'api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

serializers.py

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner',
              'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style']


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='snippet-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'username', 'snippets']
```

Traceback error:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner 34. response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response 126. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response 124. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view 54. return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view 68. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch 505. response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in handle_exception 465. self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception 476. raise exc

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch 502. response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py" in handler 50. return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ze Ran Lu\Desktop\swie\text\tutorials\snippets\views.py" in api_root 205. 'users': reverse('user-list'),

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py" in reverse 47. url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py" in _reverse 60. url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse 90. return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix 622. raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at / Exception Value: Reverse for 'user-list' not found. 'user-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Another url.py file is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('snippets.urls'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Project structure

tutorials
    |_snippets
    |    |_urls.py
    |    |_views.py
    |    |_models.py
    |    |_apps.py
    |    |_admin.py
    |_tutorials
        |_urls.py
        |_settings.py
        |_wsgi.py

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line of code `in snippets/urls.py` helped me.

```
app_name = 'snippets'
```

Comment: Владислав Доронин, please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Man? what you do?
app_name = 'snippets' 
removing of this line of code will solve problem, not adding

Answer (score -1):

reverse only accept these parameter:

> reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None,
>   current_app=None)

and your `users/` doesn't accept any arguments so you only need the url name in reverse

```
reverse('user-list')
```

Comment: After modifying according to the method you provided, the same error will still be reported

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list'),
        'snippets': reverse('snippet-list'),
    })
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-list' not found. 'user-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Comment: if that then can you post the full traceback error you got ? probably help to indicate the error come from the template or the view

Comment: The full Traceback is too long, I added an answer below

Comment: Module version is
Django                            2.1
djangorestframework               3.10.3

Comment: @ hewm do you have other urls.py files as root and use include on the file s?

Comment: Project structure is

tutorials
    |_snippets
    |    |_urls.py
    |    |_views.py
    |    |_models.py
    |    |_apps.py
    |    |_admin.py
    |_tutorials
        |_urls.py
        |_settings.py
        |_wsgi.py

The url copied in the question is  tutorials>snippets>urls.py

Another url.py file is

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('snippets.urls'))
]

Comment: I don't think this is true. It would be if you were importing `from django.urls import reverse`, but this tutorial has you importing `from rest_framework.rverse import reverse`